# How do I set a full date & time sql using java, and not just the date?

Tags: java, mysql, datetime, jdbc, prepared-statement

I am trying to set a timestamp in my database using java, however in my table all I get is the date, and no time (i.e., looks like "2010-09-09 00:00:00").

I am using a datetime field on my mysql database (because it [appears](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/409286/datetime-vs-timestamp) that [datetime is more common than timestamp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/998523/how-common-are-timestamps-over-datetime-fields)).  My code to set the date looks like this:

```
PreparedStatement ps = conn.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO mytable (datetime_field) VALUES (?)")
java.util.Date today = new java.util.Date();
java.sql.Date timestamp = new java.sql.Date(today.getTime());
ps.setDate(1, timestamp);
ps.executeUpdate();
```

How do I set the date to include the time?

**Edit:**  I changed the code as per below, and it sets both the date and the time.

```
PreparedStatement ps = conn.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO mytable (datetime_field) VALUES (?)")
java.util.Date today = new java.util.Date();
java.sql.Timestamp timestamp = new java.sql.Timestamp(today.getTime());
ps.setTimestamp(1, timestamp);
ps.executeUpdate();
```

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Use `java.sql.Timestamp` and `setTimestamp(int, Timestamp)`. `java.sql.Date` is date-only, regardless of the type of the column it's being stored in.

Answer (score 4):

Not exactly sure what you need to use, but

```
ps.setDate();
```

expects a column type of Date. So it's normalizing it, removing the time.

Try

```
ps.setTimetamp();
```

Answer (score -4):

You could use :

```
private static String getTimeStamp() {
    SimpleDateFormat f = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
    return f.format(new Date()); 
}
```

Comment: You shouldn't deal with string formats for dates/times when saving them to or reading them from a database. JDBC's abstractions such as `setTimestamp` and `getTimestamp` are there to make that unnecessary.