# UTC Problems, not sure how to fix them (PHP/MySQL)

Tags: php, mysql, timezone

I am seeing UTC date and times in all of my date/time fields on my server, I followed it all back to the timezone setup on my webserver being in UTC time... my question is how can I make these into the local users date and time?  All the times are stored in UTC on the MySQL server.

I have the users City, Region (Prov/State) and Country.  Worst case I want to display the dates and times in the PHP default time zone.

How do I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use this function, and pass it the user's location "Perth, WA, Australia" as the address.

Instead of returning 0 on failure, you could have it return the offset between the server timezone and the default php timezone.

You may want to store this in a session variable, and only call the function if the variable is empty, which would improve the speed of your page renders.

```
/**
 * This function finds the geocode of any given place using the geocoding service of yahoo
 * @example getGeoCode("White House, Washington");
 * @example getGeoCode("Machu Pichu");
 * @example getGeoCode("Dhaka");
 * @example getGeoCode("Hollywood");
 *
 * @param   string address - something you could type into Yahoo Maps and get a valid result
 * @return  int timeZoneOffset - the number of seconds difference between the user's timezone and your server's timezone, 0 if it fails.
 */
function getTimeZoneOffset($address) {
    $_url = 'http://api.local.yahoo.com/MapsService/V1/geocode';
    $_url .= sprintf('?appid=%s&location=%s',"phpclasses",rawurlencode($address));
    $_result = false;
    if($_result = file_get_contents($_url)) {
        preg_match('!<Latitude>(.*)</Latitude><Longitude>(.*)</Longitude>!U', $_result, $_match);
        $lng = $_match[2];
        $lat = $_match[1];

        $url = "http://ws.geonames.org/timezone?lat={$lat}&lng={$lng}";
        $timedata = file_get_contents($url);
        $sxml = simplexml_load_string($timedata);
        $timeZoneOffset = strtotime($sxml->timezone->time) - time();
        return $timeZoneOffset;
    }
    else
    return 0;
}
```

Code adapted from [Time Engine](http://www.phpclasses.org/browse/package/4446.html), a LGPL php class.

Answer (score 0):

In MySQL you can use the function [CONVERT_TZ](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_convert-tz) to convert all the dates to the current time zone when you select the data from the db. Another stackoverflow thread discusses [how to convert time zones using PHP 5's DateTime class.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/952975/how-can-i-easily-convert-dates-from-utc-via-php)