# PHP: Get Time for Current Region

Tags: php, timezone

I have a timezone of the user(he chooses it from a list)
I have a time in UTC(not current time)
So I need something like GetTimeForRegion(time, timezone) for PHP. Is there such functions or libraries or services?

Comment: This post seems to be similar. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/952975/how-can-i-easily-convert-dates-from-utc-via-php

Answer (score 8):

you can use DateTime::setTimezone(). If your UTC date is an UNIX timestamp, you can use some code like this :

```
$date = new DateTime();
$date->setTimezone(new DateTimeZone('UTC'));
$date->setTimestamp(1297869844);
$date->setTimezone(new DateTimeZone('Europe/Paris'));

echo $date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
// Will print 2011-02-16 16:24:04
```

Answer (score 1):

date('r') or date('c') may help you.

`echo date('r')` prints `Thu, 16 Feb 2011 16:01:07 +0200`

`echo date('c')` prints `2011-02-16T16:01:07+02:00`

Answer (score 0):

You need to look at the [Date/Time](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.datetime.php) API in PHP. I strongly advise you to stay away of gmdate and older date functions in php.

In your case, you should ask the user for its [Olson based](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tz_database) time zone.

The code of Artefact2 will do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

please write this instead : 
$date = date("Y-m-d H:i:s" , time());

so Y it means year 
 m means month 
 d means day
H get hours from 0 - 24 
h get hours from 0 to 12
i get minutes 
s get seconds