# How to use javascript vars in php?

Tags: php, javascript, mysql

Here's what im trying to do

```
<?php
    //get time from what user input on post
    $time = $_POST['time'];

 ?>
            <script type="text/javascript">
                 //convert time to utc
                 var convertedDate = dateFormat('<?php echo $time ?>', 'isoUtcDateTime');       
            </script> 
  <?php 
       $query = "INSERT INTO $table (url, time) VALUES ('$url', 'convertedDate');";
        mysql_query($query);
  ?>
```

I know you can't just place `convertedDate` in there like that, so what im asking is how would I go about doing the javascript equivalent of what i did with `<?php echo $time ?>`

Comment: Your question is "How can I create an UTC date in PHP"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Format date in PHP, with `date()` or `DateTite` object.

If you need to store other items like that, but not sa simple and JS-dependent, you should do a AJAX request to php file to store it, it's simple with jQuery and `.ajax()`

Comment: I really liked the nice simple javascript converter I found. I guess you're right i'll just have to covert the date string `07/20/2011 01:13 am` to UTC using php. Any ideas how I might convert a string like that to UTC?

Answer (score 1):

If you need to convert date in UTC.

Use `gmdate`

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.gmdate.php

Latest PHP time DateTime class can also help you

`$time = new DateTime(ew DateTimeZone('UTC'));`

Answer (score 0):

You could do it by setting up a second page containing Javascript that takes a URL query and writes the result to the page. Then use cURL to scrape the answer from the PHP.

But don't.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the following SO question [How can I easily convert dates from UTC via PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/952975/how-can-i-easily-convert-dates-from-utc-via-php) on converting a time to UTC in `php`.