# PHP Datetime issue on server

Tags: php, datetime

I'm trying to convert time of a time zone to time for another time zone as provided in [How can I easily convert dates from UTC via PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/952975/how-can-i-easily-convert-dates-from-utc-via-php) as provided below.

```
$dateTime = new DateTime("2009-04-01 15:36:13");
$dateTime->setTimezone(new DateTimeZone('Asia/Kolkata'));
echo $dateTime->format("Y-m-d H:i:s");
```

While testing at localhost, this seems to work fine but on my development server, the page throws a 500 internal server error (if called through ajax) or the page simply breaks from that line of code onwards.

Both localhost and my development server is using PHP 5.3.5.

Is there any reason why this would not be working?

Comment: Please provide the error received from your error log. The code as provided is valid.

Comment: the solution could be in this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10841960/php-class-datetime-not-found

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Check the apache error log, that should contain the exact error you get. Everything else is just wild guessing :D

Comment: Thanks I found it out in the error log. I had to specifically set my timezone `date_default_timezone_set('America/New_York');`.

Comment: Can also set your default timezone in your PHP.ini file [date.timezone](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.configuration.php#ini.date.timezone)