# PHP Class DateTime not found

Tags: php, eclipse, datetime

Missing something when declaring a DateTime object in **PHP 5.3.8**

I get a JSON string with a determinate date time which is passed to my php controller.

For some reason, I am not getting it to be mapped as a DateTime object in php. But sort of weirdly. See the following images:

1. As you can see in the Expressions Window (top right), BEFORE the step, I am checking that new DateTime(myVariable) is bringing and transforming correctly what I need. In the first watch, the variable to pass to DateTime constructor. In the second watch, the expression newDateTime(myVariable) already mapped as a DateTimeObject. Apparently fine up to here.

   [image]
2. But, sadly, when I go forward and press F6, the following exemption (see also the image below) is thrown:

   ```
   Fatal error: Class 'Acme\StoreBundle\Repository\DateTime' not found in /Users/pgbonino/Sites/Symfony/src/Acme/StoreBundle/Repository/HistoryRepository.php on line 19

   Call Stack:
       0.0201     693568   1. {main}() /Users/pgbonino/Sites/Symfony/web/app_dev.php:0
       0.0267    2106576   2. Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Kernel->handle(???, ???, ???) /Users/pgbonino/Sites/Symfony/web/app_dev.php:24
       0.0377    2649176   3. Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\HttpKernel->handle(???, ???, ???) /Users/pgbonino/Sites/Symfony/app/bootstrap.php.cache:547
       0.0378    2650832   4. Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\HttpKernel->handle(???, ???, ???) /Users/pgbonino/Sites/Symfony/app/cache/dev/classes.php:4879
       0.0378    2650832   5. Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\HttpKernel->handleRaw(???, ???) /Users/pgbonino/Sites/Symfony/app/cache/dev/classes.php:3875
       0.1574    5562232   6. call_user_func_array(???, ???) /Users/pgbonino/Sites/Symfony/app/cache/dev/classes.php:3905
       0.1574    5562600   7. Acme\StoreBundle\Controller\HistoryController->saveTestAction() /Users/pgbonino/Sites/Symfony/app/cache/dev/classes.php:3905
       0.1694    5739032   8. Acme\StoreBundle\Repository\HistoryRepository->saveTestInHistory(???, ???) /Users/pgbonino/Sites/Symfony/src/Acme/StoreBundle/Controller/HistoryController.php:33
   ```

   [image]

So, strangely, the Watch Expressions window from Eclipse is not working just like the execution engine and/or vice-versa.

Of course, I'd prefer it to be the opposite (It worked in the execution and not in the watch window :) ).

So, any idea?

Answer (score 88, accepted):

You're currently in the `Acme\StoreBundle\Repository\DateTime` napespace. To address to the default namespace in this case you need to put leading `\` before your classname, like

```
$dt = new \DateTime(...);
```

so

```
namespace foo;
$obj = new class();
```

will try to find `class` definition within `foo` namespace.

And

```
namespace foo;
$obj = new \class();
```

will try to find `class` definition within global namespace.

As an alternative you could import the class using

```
use \DateTime;
```

or create alias (in case if you already have the class with the same name in current NS):

```
use \DateTime as NewDT;
```

Comment: you could also put a `use DateTime;` on the top, and then it you are able to use it without leading slash.

Comment: Wonderful solution when using PSR-4. Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

I guess You're using namespaces and trying to use DateTime (relative to the current namespace) instead of \DateTime (the full qulified class name)